# Laravel Echo joining private channel `.here()`

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

I have a join to a private channel:

```
Echo.private('chat_room.'+comments_room_id)
.listen('.App.Events.Common.Comment.CommentCreated', function(e) {
                    e.comment.user = e.user;
                    e.comment.new_msg = 1;
                    _this.comment_room.comments.unshift(e.comment);
                });
```

I would like to use the .here() presence call to keep a array of users updated with who is currently online.

I tried the following:

```
Echo.private('chat_room.'+comments_room_id)
                    .here(users => {
                        this.users = users;
                    })
                    .listen('.App.Events.Common.Comment.CommentCreated', function(e) {
```

But that did not work...

Error in console is:
`Echo.private(...).here is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

So i discovered that you need to also join a Presence channel alongside the private channel in order to use the here() methods.

```
                Echo.join('chat_room.'+comments_room_id)
                .here((users) => {
                    this.users = users;
                })
                .joining((user) => {
                    this.users.push(user)
                })
                .leaving((person) => {
                    this.users = _.reject(this.users, user => user.id == person.id);
                });
```